# pytest-selenium: pytest_selenium_capture_debug hook is not fired on test failure

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, hook

I make e2e tests for an web app by using pytest and selenium. Everything is fine, but one thing I can't figure out though spent day searching the web.

I can't make [`pytest_selenium_capture_debug`](https://pytest-selenium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#save-screenshot-to-file) work. I put it in `conftest.py` in the root of the test sources. Tests are run inside docker container. Firefox runs with `xvfb-run`. I record screen video and want copy it to the host if test fails.

I use `python 3.6.11` and these library versions are

```
pytest==6.2.4
pytest-base-url==1.4.2
pytest-helpers-namespace==2021.4.29
pytest-html==3.1.1
pytest-lazy-fixture==0.6.3
pytest-metadata==1.11.0
pytest-repeat==0.9.1
pytest-selenium==2.0.1
pytest-variables==1.9.0
selenium==3.141.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue caused by using `custom_selenium` fixture. To make all the `pytest-selenium` hooks work properly it's necessary to use `selenium` fixture defined by `pytest-selenium` as is follows.

```
@pytest.fixture
def logged_in_selenium(selenium):
    ...
```